# JOINing three tables so that multiple column values can be replaced

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have three tables, `conference`, `game`, and `team`. Here's the definitions for each:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `game` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `home_team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `away_team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `winner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_conference` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `away_conference` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `week` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `confidence` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_game_home_team` (`home_team`),
  KEY `fk_game_away_team` (`away_team`),
  KEY `fk_game_winner` (`winner`),
  KEY `fk game_home_conference` (`home_conference`),
  KEY `fk game_away_conference` (`away_conference`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk game_away_conference` FOREIGN KEY (`away_conference`) REFERENCES `conference` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk game_home_conference` FOREIGN KEY (`home_conference`) REFERENCES `conference` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_game_away_team` FOREIGN KEY (`away_team`) REFERENCES `team` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_game_home_team` FOREIGN KEY (`home_team`) REFERENCES `team` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_game_winner` FOREIGN KEY (`winner`) REFERENCES `team` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `conference` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `team` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `conference_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_team_conference_conferenceid` (`conference_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_team_conference_conferenceid` FOREIGN KEY (`conference_id`) REFERENCES `conference` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=293 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here's some values for `game`:

```
id  home_team   away_team   winner  home_conference away_conference week    confidence

1   77  31  NULL    10  3   0   50    
2   59  96  NULL    7   12  0   50    
3   90  261 NULL    11  15  1   50
```

As you can see, the values for `home_team`, `away_team`, `home_conference`, and `away_conference` are foreign keys for the different tables. I want a query that replaces those `id`s with the actual values from the other tables in the return value when I query for all `game`s. But how can I do that? I've tried every variation of this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM game
LEFT JOIN team
ON game.home_team=team.id;
```

The problem is that these are the results:

```
id  home_team   away_team   winner  home_conference away_conference week    confidence  id  name    conference_id
1   77  31  NULL    10  3   0   50  77  Colgate 10
2   59  96  NULL    7   12  0   50  59  Youngstown State    7
3   90  261 NULL    11  15  1   50  90  Morehead State  11
```

and even though I can select the `team.name` column for this query, if I extend it to be

```sql
SELECT * FROM game
LEFT JOIN team
ON game.home_team=team.id AND game.away_team=team.id;
```

I get no results.

I'm using MariaDB, btw.

Comment: Relace * with an explicit list of columns you need

Comment: Updated my question with some more specifics for the problem. The main problem is that I can replace for ONE column but can't for multiple columns.

Comment: Join your `team` table twice (using an alias). Like: `FROM game LEFT JOIN team hometeam ON game.home_team = hometeam.id LEFT JOIN team awayteam ON game.away_team=awayteam.id` Then in your SELECT you can do `SELECT game.*, hometeam.name as home_team_name, awayteam.name as away_team_name FROM.....`

Comment: `game` references `team` 3 times - create 3 joins . `game` references `conference`  twice - create 2 more  joins.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * , 
       home.name as home_team,
       away.name as away_team
FROM game
LEFT JOIN team as home
  ON game.home_team= home.id 
LEFT JOIN team as away
  ON game.away_team= away.id
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks so much. The key was giving an alias to each `LEFT JOIN` and using separate `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: @TylerCheek, you are free to use any alias at will, but this style is a good one for sure.